# Stylus CSS Transitions

Tags: css-transitions, stylus

I've been using Stylus on a project recently, and now I'm trying to write a CSS transition. Of course, first thing you do is copy and paste the documentation's example, but I can't figure out why that won't compile. What's wrong with this Stylus?

```
$keyframe-name = pulse
@keyframes {$keyframe-name}
    for i in 0..10
        {10% * i}
            opacity (i/10)
```

In case it's relevant, I'm using the Gulp Stylus plugin to compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most obvious answer is that you have an outdated version of Stylus, try to run `npm update`. In the latest versions of Stylus everything works pretty well, see the [live demo at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/tujom/1/edit?css,output) (there is Stylus 0.47.1 ATM).

Comment: Errors finally started printing out after I updated both the Gulp plugin and Stylus, but I was still receiving errors. I checked the [GitHub issues](https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/issues/1443) and it looks like that error has been recurring. I thought Stylus was a bit more mature than this - I'm switching to LESS.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you'd report your issues, as the issue you have linked in your comment was fixed a long ago. And if there is other errors and you're not reporting them, then, ok, you can switch to whatever you wish, good luck.

Comment: Actually, compiling it with stylus from the command line rather than using the Gulp plugin works - I thought the plugin would use the globally installed Stylus but evidently not, so I guess my problem is there rather than Stylus itself.